# How to handle multiple values in a single feature?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to predict tabs position of a paragraph. In while collecting data I got some values for tab position. There may be multiple tabs in paragraph.
These are the value counts of a column
Tab Position

```
[(0.51, 4, 0.51)]                     61
[(1.0, 4, 1.0)]                       57
[(0.98, 4, 0.98)]                     41
[(0.5, 4, -0.5)]                      37
[(0.99, 4, 0.99)]                     15
[(1.5, 4, 1.5)]                        5
[(1.0, 4, 1.0), (11, 2, 9.81)]         5
[(1.01, 4, 1.01)]                      4
[(0.5, 4, 0.5)]                        3
[(11.0, 2, 9.66)]                      2
[(11.0, 2, 9.81)]                      1
```

Where
These are the positions of paragraphs where 4 means it sides values are of left indent and right  indent and 2 means right tab left side value of 2 is where the tab is positioned and right side value is from where the tab starts or tab was triggered.

How can i handle this types of multiple values and train the model?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Stepping back, what is your source material?  Why do you need to "predict" tab positions?  Why can't you just establish them directly?

Comment: The source material is Microsoft Word documents, and I need to predict tab positions using extracted features. The reason for not establishing them directly is because while working on simple documents, it is not big deal but i am dealing with some large documents and i want to automate this tedious process. "I'm stuck on finding a good way to handle these multiple tab position values. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!"